# .arangosh.rc not sourced on Mac OSX

Tags: arangodb

I am following the ArangoDB documentation, and I'm currently following the section ArangoDB Shell Configuration; here, they describe an .arangosh.rc file that is sourced from your home directory, placing custom code into the arango shell's global scope.  Following the documentation to a T, I've made an .arangosh.rc file in my home directory ~/.arangosh.rc and added the example function

```
timed = function (cb) {
  var internal = require("internal");
  var start = internal.time();
  cb();
  internal.print("execution took: ", internal.time() - start);
};
```

I've tried exiting and restarting the arango shell as well as completely restarting my terminal session but I can't get arangosh to source the rc file. When I try invoking timed() I get a

> ReferenceError: timed is not defined
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the condition for sourcing `~/.arangosh.rc` changed somewhere in 2.6, but this looks like an error to me. I have reverted that change in the 2.7, 2.8 and devel branches, so the file will get sourced there now. The fix will be contained in the next official releases.

If you want to apply it before that, the commit id for 2.7 is [8e85a2fbb67c8c50c75cf93aefb7365e1e9fd7d1](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/8e85a2fbb67c8c50c75cf93aefb7365e1e9fd7d1)

It also looks like that in 2.7 any "globals" in the rc file need to be attached to the `global` object. For example,

```
timed = function (cb) { ... };
```

should become

```
global.timed = function (cb) { ... };
```

I have also updated [the docs](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/3623b7b772f8c474f3f4cb38f158032b1a0d3b68) to reflect this change.